# Array of objects filter and get values in another structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I have data as Array of objects, i should filter the data and get objects and minimal keys with values, i have tried with loops and filter but i couldn't get as expected. I have shared the data which i have and expected structure, find the code below and please help me.

Data which i have below :

```
var data = [
  {
    "Id": 1392236,
    "foldId": 410176,
    "binding": [
      {
        "assayType": "binding",
        "activityValue": 0.03,
        "strId": 1392236
      },
      {
        "assayType": "binding",
        "activityValue": 5.0,
        "strId": 1392236
      }
    ],
    "functional invitro": [
      {
        "assayType": "functional invitro",
        "activityValue": 0.03,
        "strId": 1392236
      },
      {
        "assayType": "functional invitro",
        "activityValue": 5.0,
        "strId": 1392236
      },
      
    ],
    "functionalInvivo": [
      {
        "assayType": "functional invivo",
        "activityValue": 45.0,
        "strId": 1392236
      },
      {
        "assayType": "functional invivo",
        "activityValue": 54.0,
        "strId": 1392236
      }
    ],
    "pharmacokinetics": [
      {
        "assayType": "pharmacokinetics",
        "activityValue": 10.67,
        "strId": 1392236
      },
      {
        "assayType": "pharmacokinetics",
        "activityValue": 2.6,
        "strId": 1392236
      }          
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 1392543,
    "foldId": 410176,
    "binding": [
      {
        "assayType": "binding",
        "activityValue": 0.38,
        "strId": 1392543
      },
      {
        "assayType": "binding",
        "activityValue": 4.3,
        "strId": 1392543
      }
      
    ],
    "functional invitro": [
      {
        "assayType": "functional invitro",
        "activityValue": 2.03,
        "strId": 1392543
      },
      {
        "assayType": "functional invitro",
        "activityValue": 3.0,
        "strId": 1392543
      },
      
    ],
    "functionalInvivo": [
      {
        "assayType": "functional invivo",
        "activityValue": 25.0,
        "strId": 1392543
      },
      {
        "assayType": "functional invivo",
        "activityValue": 64.0,
        "strId": 1392543
      }
    ],
    "pharmacokinetics": [
      {
        "assayType": "pharmacokinetics",
        "activityValue": 30.67,
        "strId": 1392543
      },
      {
        "assayType": "pharmacokinetics",
        "activityValue": 5.6,
        "strId": 1392543
      }          
    ]
  }
]
```

Which am expecting after filtering like below :

```
var filterData = [
  {
      "assayType": "binding",
      "activityValue": 0.03,
      "strId": 1392543
  },
  {
      "assayType": "functional invitro",
      "activityValue": 5.0,
      "strId": 1392543
  },
  {
      "assayType": "binding",
      "activityValue": 4.3,
      "strId": 1392236
  },
  {
      "assayType": "pharmacokinetics",
      "activityValue": 6.06,
      "strId": 1392543
  },
  {
      "assayType": "functional invivo",
      "activityValue": 64,
      "strId": 1392543
  },
  {
      "assayType": "functional invivo",
      "activityValue": 4,
      "strId": 1392236
  },
  {
      "assayType": "pharmacokinetics",
      "activityValue": 6.06,
      "strId": 1392236
  },
]
```

Help me to resolve.

Comment: Can you tell me the filter condition? So you want to get filtered array of which activityValue < 10?

Comment: based on strId need to filter and it should be array of objects not nested array/objects no other conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take some unwanted properties from the objects and iterate the values for mapping the smallest ones.

```js
const
    data = [{ Id: 1392236, foldId: 410176, binding: [{ assayType: "binding", activityValue: 0.03, strId: 1392236 }, { assayType: "binding", activityValue: 5, strId: 1392236 }], "functional invitro": [{ assayType: "functional invitro", activityValue: 0.03, strId: 1392236 }, { assayType: "functional invitro", activityValue: 5, strId: 1392236 }], functionalInvivo: [{ assayType: "functional invivo", activityValue: 45, strId: 1392236 }, { assayType: "functional invivo", activityValue: 54, strId: 1392236 }], pharmacokinetics: [{ assayType: "pharmacokinetics", activityValue: 10.67, strId: 1392236 }, { assayType: "pharmacokinetics", activityValue: 2.6, strId: 1392236 }] }, { Id: 1392543, foldId: 410176, binding: [{ assayType: "binding", activityValue: 0.38, strId: 1392543 }, { assayType: "binding", activityValue: 4.3, strId: 1392543 }], "functional invitro": [{ assayType: "functional invitro", activityValue: 2.03, strId: 1392543 }, { assayType: "functional invitro", activityValue: 3, strId: 1392543 }], functionalInvivo: [{ assayType: "functional invivo", activityValue: 25, strId: 1392543 }, { assayType: "functional invivo", activityValue: 64, strId: 1392543 }], pharmacokinetics: [{ assayType: "pharmacokinetics", activityValue: 30.67, strId: 1392543 }, { assayType: "pharmacokinetics", activityValue: 5.6, strId: 1392543 }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ Id, foldId, ...o }) =>
        Object.values(o).map(array =>
            array.reduce((a, b) => a.activityValue < b.activityValue ? a : b)
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method for this,

```
data.map((item) => {
  return Object.keys(item).filter(key=> item[key].length).map((key) => item[key]).flat()
}).flat()
```

If you need to further filter data you can do that on the flat array.